# How do I get a Part in the sirius-web scripting interface?

Tags: java, sirius

When using the system scripting interface ("system/scripting") of sirius-web (part of the sirius framework), what method is available to use to get a specific registered Part to use in my script?

Answer (score 2):

Create an object implementing `sirius.web.templates.GlobalContextExtender` and add the object by extending the collectScripting Method:

```
globalParameterCollector.accept("objectNameToAccess", objectToAdd);
```

Can be accessed from within the scripting by calling:

```
@objectNameToAccess.methodName()
```

Comment: previously all parts available in java were available under ctx.getPart()/ ctx.getParts() - is something similiar no longer possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One could extend the `DefaultGlobalContextExtender` and place an instance of `Injector` in the context...